# There are Colorados everywhere!

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Deciding to go to Arizona, you go to the north part of it. But once as you arrive, you see a Colorado! We know that Colorado borders Arizona but you are far from Colorado!

Being confused, you are going to the southeastern part of Las Vegas, but you still see a Colorado! You are so confused, you decide to go to a completely different country.

That country is Cuba, and you decide to go to the western part of it. And you see a... You guessed it — Colorado.

**How did this happen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you go to:

> [Colorado City, Arizona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_City,_Arizona)

Then,

> [East Colorado Avenue, Las Vegas](https://www.google.com/maps/place/E+Colorado+Ave,+Las+Vegas,+NV+89104/@36.146007,-115.187324,10.55z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c8db5ca0d39549:0x3550cb10962988f6!8m2!3d36.155764!4d-115.076384)

And finally,

> [Colorados Archipelago, Cuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorados_Archipelago) (I initially thought [Colorado, Cuba](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Colorado,+Cuba/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8ed4e1a01886a091:0x7469a9ab3ae8fd81?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__NKPnPn0AhUMbs0KHfKRDsIQ8gF6BAgIEAE) but that's in the centerish and not the west)